# "cannot find symbol" error for Log4J, even though I'm following the tutorial

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

I'm getting the following error:

```
1 error found:
File: C:\Users\adem\Desktop\various_topics\JavaProjects\log4jExample.java  [line: 15]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getLogger(java.lang.String)
  location: interface org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
```

And here is my code, based off of this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_configuration.htm):

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;

public class log4jExample{

  /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
  static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(log4jExample.class.getName());   //.getName()
  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws IOException,SQLException{

    log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
    log.info("Hello this is an info message");
  }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the import:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

If you're using Maven you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```